# Find the text property of a textblock within a listitem

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I have a Listbox within my WP7 application, and inside the DataTemplate I have a toolkit:WrapPanel which then has a context menu (toolkit). How can I get the text of a textblock inside the listbox datatemplate when they click on the contextmenu menuitem?

Hope this makes sense heres some code:

```
                <ListBox x:Name="FirstListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="auto">
                            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="copy" Click="copytoCB_Click"></toolkit:MenuItem>
                                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding author}" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" MinWidth="430" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding content}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="txtContent" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        </toolkit:WrapPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: You could try binding the TextBlocks Text property, but i don't know where you wanna show the Text. If you wanna do something with it in the code behind then maybe as a command parameter would be the best solution.

Comment: Hey, I need the to access the text property via code behind... Can I bind to things in a command argument/parameter?

Comment: Yes you can use binding in command parameters and use this parameters in your command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see 
[WPF Commands](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CentralizingWPFCommands.aspx)
 in action, maybe a good place to start. :)